# What is the meaning behind "淵騫"?

Tags: translation

What is the verbatim meaning?
What is the meaning of the concept within Chinese philosophy?
Well i do not know why the algorithm keeps asking about the quality of standards, 
this makes me want to change to another Q&A forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are two famous disciples of Confucius. 淵: [顏淵 (顏回)](https://zh-classical.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%8F%E5%9B%9E)、騫: [閔子騫 (閔損)](https://zh-classical.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%96%94%E5%AD%90%E9%A8%AB)。

It is common practice in classical Chinese literature to label chapters in a book by the first word of substance, regardless of whether it actually pertains to the central meaning or not. In this case, the chapter begins with a question on the practices of these two disciples of Confucius, and their names are taken to form the chapter name.